# Check if an element-hash exists in an array and update it, otherwise insert it

Tags: python

I have a list of hashes:

```
[
  {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': some_object},
  {'key1': 'value21', 'key2': some_object2},
  {'key1': 'value133', 'key2': some_object3}
]
```

What's the easiest way to check if an element with `'key1': 'value133'` exists (if my case it does) and update it, (say `'key1': 'value133', 'key2': some_object333}` otherwise insert it (`{'key1': 'value133', 'key2': some_object3}`)?

Comment: If you do this often consider keeping that list sorted by the value of `key1` so you can use bisection search to find the value in O(logn) time instead of O(n) time. This doesn't matter if the list is short, but can highly improve performance if you have like hundreds or thousands elements in that list.  Or you could use a `dict` to hold all the other dicts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
l = [
  {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'some_object'},
  {'key1': 'value21', 'key2': 'some_object2'},
  {'key1': 'value133', 'key2': 'some_object3'}
]

d = any(d for d in l if d['key1'] == 'value133')
if  d:
    d['key2'] = 'some_object333'
else :
    l.append({'key1': 'value133', 'key2': 'some_object3'})

print(d)
```

do something like this  use `any()`